# Why is this svg filter producing content outside of the polygon which uses it?

Tags: svg

This svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-1 -1 2 2" width="100" height="100">
<filter id='water' x='0%' y='0%' width='100%' height='100%'>
  <feTurbulence baseFrequency="1 10" result="NOISE"/> 
  <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0  0  0  0  0
                                       0  0  0  0  0
                                       0  0  1  0  0
                                       0  0  0  1  0" />
</filter>
        <g filter="url(#water)">
                <polygon points="1.0,0.0 0.5000000000000001,0.8660254037844386 -0.4999999999999998,0.8660254037844387 -1.0,1.2246467991473532e-16 -0.5000000000000004,-0.8660254037844384 0.5000000000000001,-0.8660254037844386"></polygon>
        </g>
        <g stroke="red" stroke-width="0.05" fill="transparent">
                <polygon points="1.0,0.0 0.5000000000000001,0.8660254037844386 -0.4999999999999998,0.8660254037844387 -1.0,1.2246467991473532e-16 -0.5000000000000004,-0.8660254037844384 0.5000000000000001,-0.8660254037844386"></polygon>
        </g>
</svg>
```

renders like this

[image]

I was expecting the `#water` content to remain within the polygon, but it seems to be filling the polygon's bounding rectangle.

How can I restrict the `#water` filter such that it only effects the interior of the polygon?

Answer (score 0):

I think, reason is, because the filter is applied to the entire group `<g>` that contains the polygon, not just to the interior of the polygon.

```
<g filter="url(#water)">
            <polygon...
```

Maybe combination of masking and clipping will be good way... Try this one

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-1 -1 2 2" width="100" height="100">
  <defs>
    <filter id='water' x='0%' y='0%' width='100%' height='100%'>
      <feTurbulence baseFrequency="1 10" result="NOISE"/> 
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0  0  0  0  0
                                           0  0  0  0  0
                                           0  0  1  0  0
                                           0  0  0  1  0" />
    </filter>
    <clipPath id="polygon-clip">
      <polygon points="1.0,0.0 0.5000000000000001,0.8660254037844386 -0.4999999999999998,0.8660254037844387 -1.0,1.2246467991473532e-16 -0.5000000000000004,-0.8660254037844384 0.5000000000000001,-0.8660254037844386"></polygon>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <g clip-path="url(#polygon-clip)">
    <g filter="url(#water)">
      <rect x="-1" y="-1" width="2" height="2" fill="white"/>
    </g>
  </g>
  <g stroke="red" stroke-width="0.05" fill="transparent">
    <polygon points="1.0,0.0 0.5000000000000001,0.8660254037844386 -0.4999999999999998,0.8660254037844387 -1.0,1.2246467991473532e-16 -0.5000000000000004,-0.8660254037844384 0.5000000000000001,-0.8660254037844386"></polygon>
  </g>
</svg>
```